# How do I make a drop down list follow links from a selection?

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, dynamic-programming

I am using a PHP array and foreach loop to create a drop down list of the 50 US states with links to each of their COVID-19 response pages.

When the "Go" button is clicked, it should take you to the selected state's link.

I run tests, but the "Go" button does not work for any of the selections.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        $states = array(
            "Alabama" => "governor.alabama.gov/newsroom/covid-19",
            "Alaska" => "dhss.alaska.gov/dph/Epi/id/Pages/COVID-19/default.aspx",
            "Arizona" => "www.azdhs.gov/index.php",
            "Arkansas" => "www.healthy.arkansas.gov/programs-services/topics/novel-coronavirus",
            "California" => "www.cdcr.ca.gov/covid19/",
            "Colorado" => "covid19.colorado.gov/",
            "Connecticut" => "portal.ct.gov/Coronavirus",
            "Delaware" => "coronavirus.delaware.gov/",
            "District of Columbia" => "https://coronavirus.dc.gov/",
            "Florida" => "www.floridadisaster.org/covid19/",
            "Georgia" => "georgia.gov/covid-19-state-services-georgia",
            "Hawaii" => "health.hawaii.gov/coronavirusdisease2019/",
            "Idaho" => "coronavirus.idaho.gov/",
            "Illinois" => "coronavirus.illinois.gov/s/",
            "Indiana" => "coronavirus.in.gov/",
            "Iowa" => "coronavirus.iowa.gov/",
            "Kansas" => "govstatus.egov.com/coronavirus",
            "Kentucky" => "governor.ky.gov/covid19",
            "Louisiana" => "ldh.la.gov/coronavirus/",
            "Maine" => "www.maine.gov/covid19/",
            "Maryland" => "coronavirus.maryland.gov/",
            "Massachusetts" => "www.mass.gov/resource/information-on-the-outbreak-of-coronavirus-disease-2019-covid-19",
            "Michigan" => "www.michigan.gov/coronavirus",
            "Minnesota" => "mn.gov/covid19/",
            "Mississippi" => "msdh.ms.gov/msdhsite/_static/14,0,420.html#Mississippi",
            "Missouri" => "dss.mo.gov/covid-19/",
            "Montana" => "covid19.mt.gov/",
            "Nebraska" => "dhhs.ne.gov/pages/Coronavirus.aspx",
            "Nevada" => "nvhealthresponse.nv.gov/",
            "New Hampshire" => "www.nh.gov/covid19/",
            "New Jersey" => "www.nj.gov/health/cd/topics/covid2019_community.shtml",
            "New Mexico" => "www.dws.state.nm.us/COVID-19-Info",
            "New York" => "coronavirus.health.ny.gov/home",
            "New York City" => "www1.nyc.gov/site/coronavirus/index.page",
            "North Carolina" => "www.ncdhhs.gov/divisions/public-health/covid19",
            "North Dakota" => "www.ndresponse.gov/covid-19-resources",
            "Ohio" => "coronavirus.ohio.gov/wps/portal/gov/covid-19/home",
            "Oaklahoma" => "coronavirus.health.ok.gov/",
            "Oregon" => "coronavirus.oregon.gov/",
            "Pennsylvania" => "www.health.pa.gov/topics/disease/coronavirus/Pages/Coronavirus.aspx",
            "Rhode Island" => "www.ride.ri.gov/InsideRIDE/AdditionalInformation/Covid19.aspx",
            "South Carolina" => "www.scdhec.gov/infectious-diseases/viruses/coronavirus-disease-2019-covid-19",
            "South Dakota" => "covid.sd.gov/",
            "Tennessee" => "www.tn.gov/governor/covid-19.html",
            "Texas" => "dshs.texas.gov/coronavirus/",
            "Utah" => "coronavirus.utah.gov/",
            "Vermont" => "www.healthvermont.gov/response/coronavirus-covid-19",
            "Virgina" => "www.vdh.virginia.gov/coronavirus/",
            "Washington" => "coronavirus.wa.gov/",
            "West Virginia" => "dhhr.wv.gov/COVID-19/Pages/default.aspx",
            "Wisconsin" => "www.dhs.wisconsin.gov/covid-19/index.html",
            "Wyoming" => "health.wyo.gov/publichealth/infectious-disease-epidemiology-unit/disease/novel-coronavirus/"
            );
            ?>

            <form action="" method="POST">
                <select name="states" id="states">

                    <?php

                    foreach ($states as $array_key => $array_value) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="https://<?php echo $array_value; ?>"><?php echo $array_key; ?></option>
                    <?php
                    } //end loop

                    ?>

                </select>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
            </form>

            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $option = $_POST['states'];

                header("Location: " . $option);
            }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-send header (line: 81) after have already sended (line: 67).

I suggest you to re-organize your code, for example:

```
<html>
    <body>
          <?php
            $states = array(
            "Alabama" => "governor.alabama.gov/newsroom/covid-19",
            "Alaska" => "dhss.alaska.gov/dph/Epi/id/Pages/COVID-19/default.aspx",
            "Arizona" => "www.azdhs.gov/index.php",
            "Arkansas" => "www.healthy.arkansas.gov/programs-services/topics/novel-coronavirus",
            "California" => "www.cdcr.ca.gov/covid19/",
            "Colorado" => "covid19.colorado.gov/",
            "Connecticut" => "portal.ct.gov/Coronavirus",
            "Delaware" => "coronavirus.delaware.gov/",
            "District of Columbia" => "https://coronavirus.dc.gov/",
            "Florida" => "www.floridadisaster.org/covid19/",
            "Georgia" => "georgia.gov/covid-19-state-services-georgia",
            "Hawaii" => "health.hawaii.gov/coronavirusdisease2019/",
            "Idaho" => "coronavirus.idaho.gov/",
            "Illinois" => "coronavirus.illinois.gov/s/",
            "Indiana" => "coronavirus.in.gov/",
            "Iowa" => "coronavirus.iowa.gov/",
            "Kansas" => "govstatus.egov.com/coronavirus",
            "Kentucky" => "governor.ky.gov/covid19",
            "Louisiana" => "ldh.la.gov/coronavirus/",
            "Maine" => "www.maine.gov/covid19/",
            "Maryland" => "coronavirus.maryland.gov/",
            "Massachusetts" => "www.mass.gov/resource/information-on-the-outbreak-of-coronavirus-disease-2019-covid-19",
            "Michigan" => "www.michigan.gov/coronavirus",
            "Minnesota" => "mn.gov/covid19/",
            "Mississippi" => "msdh.ms.gov/msdhsite/_static/14,0,420.html#Mississippi",
            "Missouri" => "dss.mo.gov/covid-19/",
            "Montana" => "covid19.mt.gov/",
            "Nebraska" => "dhhs.ne.gov/pages/Coronavirus.aspx",
            "Nevada" => "nvhealthresponse.nv.gov/",
            "New Hampshire" => "www.nh.gov/covid19/",
            "New Jersey" => "www.nj.gov/health/cd/topics/covid2019_community.shtml",
            "New Mexico" => "www.dws.state.nm.us/COVID-19-Info",
            "New York" => "coronavirus.health.ny.gov/home",
            "New York City" => "www1.nyc.gov/site/coronavirus/index.page",
            "North Carolina" => "www.ncdhhs.gov/divisions/public-health/covid19",
            "North Dakota" => "www.ndresponse.gov/covid-19-resources",
            "Ohio" => "coronavirus.ohio.gov/wps/portal/gov/covid-19/home",
            "Oaklahoma" => "coronavirus.health.ok.gov/",
            "Oregon" => "coronavirus.oregon.gov/",
            "Pennsylvania" => "www.health.pa.gov/topics/disease/coronavirus/Pages/Coronavirus.aspx",
            "Rhode Island" => "www.ride.ri.gov/InsideRIDE/AdditionalInformation/Covid19.aspx",
            "South Carolina" => "www.scdhec.gov/infectious-diseases/viruses/coronavirus-disease-2019-covid-19",
            "South Dakota" => "covid.sd.gov/",
            "Tennessee" => "www.tn.gov/governor/covid-19.html",
            "Texas" => "dshs.texas.gov/coronavirus/",
            "Utah" => "coronavirus.utah.gov/",
            "Vermont" => "www.healthvermont.gov/response/coronavirus-covid-19",
            "Virgina" => "www.vdh.virginia.gov/coronavirus/",
            "Washington" => "coronavirus.wa.gov/",
            "West Virginia" => "dhhr.wv.gov/COVID-19/Pages/default.aspx",
            "Wisconsin" => "www.dhs.wisconsin.gov/covid-19/index.html",
            "Wyoming" => "health.wyo.gov/publichealth/infectious-disease-epidemiology-unit/disease/novel-coronavirus/"
            );
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $option = $_POST['states'];
                //header("Location: $option");
                //using javascript
                echo "<script>window.location.href='{$option}';</script>";
                exit();
            }else{
            ?>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <select name="states" id="states">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($states as $array_key => $array_value) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="https://<?php echo $array_value; ?>"><?php echo $array_key; ?></option>
                    <?php
                    } //end loop
                    ?>
                </select>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
            </form>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi there.

Thank you for answering, but this does not solve my issue. I ran it, and the drop-down box just disappears when "Go" is clicked.

Comment: I know, it disappear because the site redirect you to the domain selected, is not right? What functionality you want?

Comment: I would like the site to redirect to the domain selected, like you said.
Here is the test I am running. I copied and pasted the code exactly.
https://covidinfo.app/states_test.php

Comment: I have tested in my server and it works. Anyway i have edited the code with a new method, check it out, now is using javascript and not Header location :) try now :) let me know if it works

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. And I believe you that it worked the first time. I think something is up with my web-server provider.
Thank you for being so patient with this.